# Merging a fix from release to develop when pull requests/gated checkins are mandatory

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, pull-request, git-flow

Say i have a project with multiple delivered and supported releases and a develop with not yet released features:

- release/1.0
- release/2.0
- release/2.1
- develop

A bug is reported for 2.1. I test or check the code and find, its there since 2.0. So I create a hotfix branch fix it and merge it to release/2.0. Now i have to merge release/2.0->release/2.1 and release/2.1->develop. good.

What happens if one of the branches is protected by pull requests or gated checkin? I will probably start a pull request release/2.0->release/2.1. If the merge is simple, git will fix it and der pull request is ok.

When the merge needs manual attention or the fix is obsolete (now i would usually use the `ours` merge strategy), is there anything I can do except a new hotfix branch on the target?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new branch from the source release, e.g. release/2.0.
Now you can merge the changes from the target release, e.g. release/2.1 into the new branch. The merge can use "--theirs" to ignore the changes from release/2.0 or you can do some manual changes afterwards. 
At the end you can create a pull request from the new branch to the target release, e.g. release/2.1.